# Sending back exit signal to gitlab pipeline

Tags: bash, gitlab-ci, cicd, gcloud-compute

Is there any way to send back exit signal from the bash script to the GitLab pipeline script?

What I'm trying to do simple looks like:

```
install:
  stage: install
  
  script:
    - |
       echo "Dummy dry-run installation"
       chmod +x ./install-dry-run.sh
       ./install-dry-run.sh $SA_EMAIL $PROJECT_ID
  rules:
    - when: never
```

and bash script:

```
gcloud compute ssh ${instance_name} \
--quiet --tunnel-through-iap --zone=us-east4-c --ssh-key-expire-after=30s \
--project=${PROJECT_ID} \
--impersonate-service-account=${SA_EMAIL} \
--command="\
  if [ -f "/path/to/my/file.txt" ]; then echo 'Process successful'; else echo 'Process failed'; exit 1 > /dev/null; fi \
  " \
  -- -n
```

but that will not fail when the file is not present.

PS.
Proposed solution didn't worked:

```
Process failed
$ if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then # collapsed multi-line command
Installation successful
```

Comment: it's better to use the `exit` command with a specific exit code to indicate success or failure!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working but kind of "dirty" solution for `install-dry-run.sh` :

```
gcloud compute ssh ${instance_name} \
--quiet --tunnel-through-iap --zone=us-east4-c --ssh-key-expire-after=30s \
--project=${PROJECT_ID} \
--impersonate-service-account=${SA_EMAIL} \
--command="\
  if [ -f "/path/to/my/file.txt" ]; then echo 'success'; else echo 'failure'; fi; \
  " \
-- -n > status.txt

if grep -q failure status.txt; then
   echo "Installation failed"
   exit 1
else 
   echo "Installation successful"
fi
```